# .hover() and .click() don't work in conjunction with each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Probably a rookie mistake, but I can't seem to get the following to work;

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
  $("div.button_normal").hover(
     function() { $(this).removeClass("button_normal").addClass("button_hover"); },
     function() { $(this).removeClass("button_hover").addClass("button_normal"); }
    );  
  $("div.button_normal").click(
     function() { $(this).removeClass("button_normal") }
    )
});
```

If I pull out `.hover()`, it works fine, however, when `.hover()` is included, it overwrites `.click()`.

Could anyone help me fix it up?

Comment: you should be able to do all this ini your css

Comment: With the indentation fixed, it reveals a few missing `;` in the `.click()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're binding `click` via a class selector, but on `hover`, you're removing that class. Hence `click` is not firing.

You can use an id selector or add another class like `button` for example, that doesn't get removed on `hover`.

Comment: I've now got this, however .click() only holds for the duration of the hover.


`$(document).ready( function() { 
 $("div.button_normal").hover(
 function() { $(this).removeClass("button_normal").addClass("button_hover"); },
 function() { $(this).removeClass("button_hover").addClass("button_normal"); }); 
 $("#button_2").click(
 function() { $(this).removeClass("button_hover").addClass("button_active"); })
});`

Comment: Thanks in advance for taking a look by the way.

Comment: That's because, `onMouseOut` your hover handler is resetting the style. I updated your fiddle to check for active condition before resetting the style. http://jsfiddle.net/92U9z/2/